# clickable card view simple without recycler view

Tags: java, android-linearlayout, cardview

I have a fragment and have linear layout that contains 2 simple card views.

How can I make card view clickable cardviews?

I have searched, but all topics are about cardviews in recycler view ... But I have a simple clickable cardview.

```
public class popFragment extends Fragment {

    public popFragment()
    {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.popfragment,container,false);
        return view;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply assign id in your layout xml to each card view. then in oncreateView() of the fragment bind the view and use mycardView.setOnclickListener.... .

```
    public class popFragment extends Fragment {

    private CardView cardView1;
    private CardView cardView2;

        public popFragment()
        {
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        }

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.popfragment,container,false);
    cardView1 = view.findViewById(R.id.my_card_view_1);
    cardView2 = view.findViewById(R.id.my_card_view_2);

    cardView1.setOnClickListener(v->{
       //set on click functions here
    });

    cardView2.setOnClickListener(v->{
       //set on click functions here
    });

            return view;
        }
    }
```

do not forget to assign the corresponding ids in your layout.xml